Does "go with the flow" have 2 meanings?
According to Cambridge Dictionary

go with the flow: to do what other people are doing or agree with the
opinions of others:
When you’re new in a school, it’s easiest to just go with the flow for
a while, and see what people are like.

But Britannica says

go with the flow : to relax and accept what is happening without
trying to change things or do something different or difficult When
I'm on vacation, I just like to take it easy and go with the flow.

I don't know why the dictionaries don't show 2 meanings but just one.
So, I guess "go with the flow" can be

Adapting to Circumstances
Meaning: Accepting situations as they are without resistance.
Example: "I got stuck in the traffic jam. I didn't go mad but went with the flow."

Conforming to the Group
Meaning: Doing what others are doing to avoid conflict or stand out.
Example: "Everyone wants to go to the movies, so I guess I'll just go with the flow."



But 'doing what others are doing to avoid conflict' is exactly 'adapting to circumstances'. The two differing explanations are not in opposition, rather, they supplement each other.

I don't know why the dictionaries don't show 2 meanings but just one. You mean I don't know why both dictionaries don't show the same meaning.  The sense is "let yourself be carried along by the current" (as in a river), so they are two slightly different ways of interpreting the idea.

I simply can't see "two different meanings" here (unless we count the literal and metaphorical meanings separately). Going with the (more literal) "flow of traffic" and (more metaphorically) going along with whatever everyone else is doing look the same to me. In both cases, it's just conforming.

It is a figurative expression based on the notion that it is difficult to swim against the current. It's much easier to let the current take you.   You apply that by analogy to whatever situation is at hand.
strenuous : swimming against the current :: difficulty : some situation 


I'm not going to stick my neck out in my first week on the job. I'm going to go with the flow for a while.
We're  not sure if we want to move in together. We're just going to go with the flow for a while.
The cyclist was in  the midst of the peloton and thought it  too soon to make a move. She was going to go with the flow for a while.

The expression favors certain kinds of contexts but in and of itself it doesn't really have a fixed definition, apart from its literal meaning of being carried by the current.
